# Does folder permission leads any error

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport, time, estimate

I am not able to import and export my products, but one thing partially export working, which means 100's products successfully exported, but 1000's of products not able to export (In my site consists 20,000 products),

Answer (score 0):

Might be issue with php memory limit ,
Increase  `php_value memory_limit` value in your root .htaccess file and try again.

Hope this will work.

Comment: bro, am try lots of combination, but didn't work

Comment: also try what you told

Comment: is any other possibilities of this error

Comment: create a shell script for export and run from terminal, this always work for me.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/UgwgjSk.png

Comment: follow this tutorial http://inchoo.net/magento/php-shell-scripts-for-magento/ and load product collection and write the data in file using loop.

Comment: Thank you for your help, may i know why am getting error no valid data send during product export